# ubuntu 18.04 chrome can not open display

Tags: google-chrome, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-18.04

Using Ubuntu 18.04 on AWS, (ubuntu/images/hvm-ssd/**ubuntu-bionic-18.04-amd64-server**-20190722.1 )
I logged in into the EC2 using Putty
 installed chrome, when I try to launch chrome- get this error
(google-chrome:13071): Gtk-WARNING **: 19:13:42.804: **cannot open display**

How do I solve this

Comment: Did you get any solution to this?

Comment: No, its still out there

Comment: Never mind. Got the solution.
Try finding if DISPLAY is set.
`echo $DISPLAY` 
In my case, it was not. Once, I set that to the port I ran the VNC in, it started running.
`export DISPLAY=:1`